# Get user profile information using google apis in c#

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to get gapps user profile information using google apis & `OAUTH2` in c#.

Which DLL & scopes should I use to get user profile information after token generation?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Why don't you tell us what you have tried, if you are having trouble with your code you will need to post that and any error messages.  We wont google the answers for you.

Comment: I did not tried. I am not getting any dll or scope that will give me user profile information.